# plotting function does not display any graph

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, wavelet

what i am trying to achieve using the below mentioned code is,to draw, in one plot, four signals `x1, x2, x3, x4` each with `t1, t2, t3, t4` respectively. so that, each one fourth of a second anew signal with different frequency to be plotted. But, when i run the code, the plot displays nothing just an empty graph.

Kindly please let me know what i am missing in the code.

**Code**

```
% Time specifications:
Fs = 8000;                       % samples per second
dt = 1/Fs;                       % seconds per sample
StopTime = 1;                    % seconds
t = (0:dt:StopTime);         % seconds

t1 = (0:dt:.25);
t2 = (.25:dt:.50);
t3 = (.5:dt:.75);
t4 = (.75:dt:1);

x1 = (10)*cos(2*pi*3*t1);
x2 = (20)*cos(2*pi*6*t2);
x3 = (30)*cos(2*pi*10*t3);
x4 = (50)*cos(2*pi*15*t4);

% Plot the signal versus time:
figure;
xlabel('time (in seconds)');
ylabel('Amplitude');
title('Signal versus Time');
plot(t,x1,'r');
plot(t,x2,'g');
plot(t,x3,'b');
plot(t,x4,'black');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the last four lines by

```
hold on %// this prevents each subsequent `plot` from removing the previous graph
plot(t1,x1,'r'); %// use appropriate "t" vector: `t1` in this case
plot(t2,x2,'g');
plot(t3,x3,'b');
plot(t4,x4,'black');
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, no it works. but when ii changed all of t1, t2, t3, t4 and replaced them by t, the plot displayed nothing again, would you please tell me why that is happeneing

Comment: You can't use `plot(t,x1)` because `t` and `x1` don't have the same size (`plot` issues an error)

Comment: You could use `plot(t1,x1); plot(t1,x2);` etc. I guess this would produce the desired results.